# How to map java.time.LocalDate field with Orika?

Tags: java, orika

This occurs because LocalDate is not a [JavaBean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) (it has no zero-arg constructor)

To fix this, you need to create a LocalDateConverter :

```
public class LocalDateConverter extends BidirectionalConverter<LocalDate, LocalDate> {

  @Override
  public LocalDate convertTo(LocalDate source, Type<LocalDate> destinationType) {
    return (source);
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDate convertFrom(LocalDate source, Type<LocalDate> destinationType) {
    return (source);
  }

}
```

and then register it adding this line :

```
mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new LocalDateConverter());
```

As a shorcut, you can instead register the provided "PassThroughConverter" as suggested by Adam Michalik so Orika doesn't try to instanciate a new "LocalDate" :

```
mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new PassThroughConverter(LocalDate.class));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This occurs because LocalDate is not a [JavaBean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) (it has no zero-arg constructor)

To fix this, you need to create a LocalDateConverter :

```
public class LocalDateConverter extends BidirectionalConverter<LocalDate, LocalDate> {

  @Override
  public LocalDate convertTo(LocalDate source, Type<LocalDate> destinationType) {
    return (LocalDate.from(source));
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDate convertFrom(LocalDate source, Type<LocalDate> destinationType) {
    return (LocalDate.from(source));
  }

}
```

and then register it adding this line :

```
mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new LocalDateConverter());
```

Answer (score 17):

Even better, since `LocalDate` is immutable, there's no harm in using the same object in the source and target beans. You can configure your `MapperFactory` as follows:

```
mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new PassThroughConverter(LocalDate.class));
```

Comment: The source and the target are not beans, and I don't see how an immutable object could be reused with a new value since it's "immutable" (Immutable objects are simply objects whose state (the object's data) cannot change after construction).

Comment: Have you tried running it with the PassThroughConverter? What I understand, you don't want to have have a LocalDate with a new value - you want the target LocalDate to have the same value as the source LocalDate. Since LocalDate is immutable, you don't need to create a new LocalDate object to achieve that - you can use the same object for target as for source.

Comment: mmm ok, you're right, I forgot about my use case. If it works, your solution is cleaner. I don't know why I wrote "return (LocalDate.from(source))" instead of "return source"

Answer (score 1):

OrikaMapper has fixed this in the 1.5.1 release.
You can upgrade your dependency to 1.5.1 and it should be added there automatically.
No need of adding a converter.
Here are the release notes for 1.5.1:
https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/issues/179

PR for the fix:
https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/pull/178

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This should be the way to go now. It's way cleaner and faster.