# Orika Mapper - Cannot register converters after MapperFacade has been initialized

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mapping, orika

I have created a class to copy bean properties using Orika Mapper API in spring boot application as shown below:

```
public class ObjectMapper {

    private static MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

    public static ClientEntity toClientEntity(ClientDTO clientDTO) {
        BoundMapperFacade<ClientDTO, ClientEntity> boundMapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(ClientDTO.class, ClientEntity.class);
        return boundMapper.map(clientDTO);
    }   

    public static UserEntity toUserEntity(UserDTO userDTO) {
        mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new PassThroughConverter(LocalDate.class));
        mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new PassThroughConverter(LocalTime.class));
        BoundMapperFacade<UserDTO, UserEntity> boundMapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(UserDTO.class, UserEntity.class);
        return boundMapper.map(userDTO);
    }
}
```

UserEntity & UserDTO POJO classes have JAVA 8 LocalDate and LocalTime properties so have registeredConverters for mapperFactory. This works fine for first time but on consecutive call it throws the below exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot register converters after MapperFacade has been initialized
    at ma.glasnost.orika.converter.DefaultConverterFactory.registerConverter(DefaultConverterFactory.java:192) ~[orika-core-1.4.6.jar:na]
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory$ConverterFactoryFacade.registerConverter(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1614) ~[orika-core-1.4.6.jar:na]
```

I understand this is because converters are being registered after MapperFacade is initialized. How to resolve this issue? How to register converters before initialization?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map java.time.LocalDate field with Orika?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805753/how-to-map-java-time-localdate-field-with-orika)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In provided snippet you are trying to register converters every time `toUserEntity()` is called. So, the first call would work, but the second would fail because the `MapperFacade` would be already initialized during the first call.

You may move converters registration from mapping method to the static block like this:

```
private static MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
static {
    mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new PassThroughConverter(LocalDate.class));
    mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new PassThroughConverter(LocalTime.class));
}
```

Also, you may prefer to move `BoundMapperFacade`'s to the static fields to avoid unnecessary `getMapperFacade` calls, like this:

```
private static BoundMapperFacade<ClientDTO, ClientEntity> clientBoundMapper 
                     = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(ClientDTO.class, ClientEntity.class);
private static BoundMapperFacade<UserDTO, UserEntity> userBoundMapper 
                     = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(UserDTO.class, UserEntity.class);
```

So the mapping methods will turn into simple one-liners:

```
public static ClientEntity toClientEntity(ClientDTO clientDTO) {
    return clientBoundMapper.map(clientDTO);
}   

public static UserEntity toUserEntity(UserDTO userDTO) {
    return userBoundMapper.map(userDTO);
}
```